# Installshield- Custom action reverts the installation when Synchronous return processing is used

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield, custom-action, failed-installation

I've been assigned the task of performing a silent installation by wrapping an exe and its iss file into a msi installer using installshield. I was able to get everything working by using a exe custom action and setting the following

Retturn Processing to Asynchronous (No wait for completion) 
In-script Execution as Commin Execution. 
Install Exec Sequence: Just before InstallFinalize
Install Exec Condition: Not Installed

The problem here is that the msi installer does not wait for the completion of the exe installer. And if i set the Return Processing to Synchronous (wait for or ignore code) it installs the files and then reverts the installation before completion of the msi installer.

I'm stuck here and know not what to do. Any suggestions/help please. I have searched the web but with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not that Windows Installer doesn't wait - this would be a bug that would be immediately noticed. The issue is most likely that many setup programs that are initiated with an exe launcher do not wait until the entire install is finished. These launchers exit as soon as the actual internal install process is started. For example, the InstallShield setup.exe has a /w command line option that makes it wait until the MSI install process has completed, but by default it terminates much sooner.